# Image inside hyperlink not working in Visualforce page rendered as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, outputlink, renderas

I am trying to create hyperlink in PDF using visualforce renderAs = "pdf".
Actually I don't want the simple link i.e. text link, instead of text link I want image icon and on click of that icon/image the site should open browser.

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://www.xyz.com">
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.icon}" alt="icon"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

Using above code, the icon is properly visible in PDF but does not act as a hyperlink. Is it even possible? Please help.

Comment: did you try wrapping it in an `<a href="..........><apex:image......../></a>`

Comment: Yes I tried that, but didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work on my system by going with pure html:

```
<a href="https://www.xyz.com">
    <img src="{!$Resource.icon}" alt="icon"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works perfectly for me. Actually conclusion is <apex:image> tag is not working with anchor tag

Comment: Interesting. `<apex: outputlink>` and `<apex:image>` are on the list of [Components That Are Safe When Rendering as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm). Glad you got it sorted. By chance, was this an HTML5 page or was there anything else unique about it, such as a class applied to the image/link?

Comment: @crmprogdev I was surprised too, but I was able to reproduce the problem just by putting the `<apex:outputLink>` and `<apex:image>` in a `<apex:page renderas="pdf">` tag without doing anything else. Using an `<apex:outputLink>` and a `<img>` tag didn't work for me either, I was only able to get it to work with the pure html version.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if it has something to do with the type of image being an `icon` as opposed to a `jpg` or `png`. Very curious behavior. Thanks for reporting back. Good info to share.